# Too many arguments to method call error when using sizeWithAtrributes in ios 7 iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uifont

Previously in my application i was using `sizeWithFont` like this.

Im trying to adjust the size and position of an image according to the text label width and position. so i try i like this,

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x + [self.categoryLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.categoryLabel.font].width + 10, y, _imageSize.width, _imageSize.height);
```

But in iOS 7 it is deprecated and asked to sizeWithAttributes.

When i tried like this i was getting the "x" cordinate like this.
[image: Before deprecating]

But when i use the code like this `CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x + [self.categoryLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.categoryLabel.frame.size.width+10]}],y,_imageSize.width,_imageSize.height);`

im getting the "x" cordinate like this.

[image: After deprecation]

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
self.categoryLabel.font.width+10
```

with

```
self.categoryLabel.frame.size.width+10
```

There is no property width on font. I assume you want to get width from frame of your label.

// EXTENDED

This is an example of whole rect creation line, CGRect expect 4 parameters, I listed it line by line separated by coma, I'm not sure is it what you need but it will give you some result:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x + [self.categoryLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.categoryLabel.font.pointSize]}].width, //<- this .width takes width ot the size with font but maybe you required height
y,
_imageSize.width,
_imageSize.height);
```

If you have a look on the line below (your old one) there is not 4 parameters:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x + [self.categoryLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[self.categoryLabel.frame.size.width]+10,y,_imageSize.width,_im‌​ageSize.height]}];
```

it looks like it's just one so it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. i tried in this way  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x + [self.categoryLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[self.categoryLabel.frame.size.width]+10,y,_imageSize.width,_imageSize.height]}];  Now it is showing "Expected identifier" error.

Comment: @suji I edited my post again. It was mistake in my code. For now I assume that you want to get width of the sizeWithFont: method, but to be honest I don't know what do you want to achieve. Your question is how to fix an error and the edited code should do that.

Comment: Thanks it worked. i edited my question can you please help with that.

Comment: @suji this is not related to this question you should create another post. However in your first example you call sizeWithFont: and you pass font from your label as a parameter (which is right) but in the other code in method systemFontOfSize: you dont pass font size, you pass: self.categoryLabel.frame.size.width+10 label width plus 10 which is not relevant to the size of the font. Try use self.categoryLabel.font.pointSize instead, which should be equivalent to the first example.